# Post is not showing up in facebook page posted by graph Api Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

Post is not showing up in facebook page.

I created access token and in second text box I entered "my page id ?feed/"  next to POST. After I created few fields (description , message ) and after submission I got the result "True"  but when i go to page I don't see any post on page.

**How I created Access Token:**

I selected app from top where 2 options were given (Graph API Explorer, My application), I selected "My Application"
To get token I selected "Get Page Access Token " from next option and then I selected Page.

Following response I got but post does not show up in page.

```
{
  "success": true
}
```

What could be the reason for this.

Comment: The correct path is `/page-id/feed`. A successful post will return a post id, not just “success”.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, it is done